# Using ARG in my Dockerfile but still getting "Failed to replace env in config" when running my build

Tags: docker, dockerfile, environment-variables, docker-build, npmrc

I have this file (.npmrc.docker)

```
//registry.npmjs.org/:_authToken=${NPM_TOKEN}
```

And in my Docker file I have

```
ARG NPM_TOKEN
RUN mv .npmrc.docker .npmrc
RUN yarn install
```

However when I run my Docker build with

```
NPM_TOKEN=mySecretToken docker build .
```

I get this error

```
#41 0.710 error An unexpected error occurred: "Failed to replace env in config: ${NPM_TOKEN}".
```

What’s the proper way to pass an environment variable into my Docker build?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`docker build --build-arg NPM_TOKEN=mySecretToken .` should do the job

Ref [here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/#set-build-time-variables---build-arg)

Comment: to complement your answer, here is the [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/#set-build-time-variables---build-arg)